# Problems to install VLC ActiveX plugin in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, installation, 64-bit, activex, vlc

I am having real difficulties installing VLC ActiveX plugin in Microsoft Access.

I have downloaded the last version of VLC from VideoLan website, marked the ActiveX installation, and referenced the VideoLan library under "References" within Access. I have also registered the ActiveX component using regsvr32.

I have tried to register the 64-bit version in the \windows\system32\regsvr32 version but I get a compatibility (32x64-bit) compatibility error. If I run \windows\syswow64\regsvr32 axvlc.dll then I get I successful message but, as is my understanding, I am registering a 32-bit version which is not compatible with my 64-bit MS Access. I have tried to find a 64-bit ActiveX version of VLC but failed to find.

Nevertheless, even with a successful registration of the 32-bit VLC ActiveX plugin, I cannot find the VLC control in the "Insert ActiveX control" within Access. I am stuck. Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Guys!
Found an answer
On the VideoLan Download website page, I've noticed an arrow next to the download button. Clicking that arrow you can select the 64-bit version. The default download is the 32-bit version, so be careful there.
Then followed the correct procedures:

- To hold adm status opened the cmd windows
  typed CMD in the command bar (lower left Windows screen) and then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

-Navigate to where the 64-bit version was installed (default directory)
cd\program files\VideoLan\VLC

-Run regsvr32 from the 64-bit directory
\windows\system32\regsvr32 axvlc.dll
(got a successful message)

- Entered Access and typed ALT+F11
- Clicked in Tools\References and selected: "VideoLAN VLC ActiveX Plugin"
- In form design mode, selected "Insert ActiveX Control"
- Finally, selected "VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v2"

Voila - The control was added to the form